# Rspec test - keep executing a method until the error message is no longer raised

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to Rspec, so sorry if this is a bad question. In one of the test tests I'm running, I have code which uses a random number generator to determine whether or not a method should be executed. If it cannot be executed, the method raises an error message.

So I need to write a test which continually runs the method on a small array of class objects until it no longer receives the error message. So in effect each class object will eventually successfully execute that method after a few tries.

The array has 6 items. I'm hoping that I need to loop through each one and then use a while loop which then tests whether the error message has been executed, but I haven't got a clue how. Any help gratefully appreciated.

I have something like this at the moment...

```
 def create_planes
    6.times do
      plane=Plane.new
      planes<<plane
    end  
  end

  it 'should land each plane' do
    create_planes

    i = 0
    while i<planes.count
      begin
        airport.plane_land(planes[i]) 
        i++
      rescue  
        next
      end 
    end

    expect(airport.plane_count).to eq(6)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally with RSpec, you'll set up your inputs and test your outputs. You wouldn't execute until an error occurs, you'd execute a known number of lands and then check that the airport's plane changed to what you expect.

```
it "should maintain a list of landed planes" do
  expect {
    3.times { airport.plane_land Plane.new }
  }.to change { airport.plane_count }.from(0).to(3)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comment. When you say set up your inputs, do you create your tests first before your code, or do you refactor each as you go along. Im struggling with the TDD process.

Comment: "Proper" TDD expects that you set up the tests before you code. In practicality, I usually end up just refactoring as I go. When I say "set up your inputs" I just mean that you define "this is expected input" and "this is expected output" in RSpec, and then you invoke your code with your set inputs and check that they match the set outputs.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the balance between refactoring, testing and predictable inputs, outputs had thrown me, but I'm slowly getting there.